# Is there any options for gridOptions in Angular js like the one in api.redrawRows in AG Grid?

Tags: angular, angularjs, grid

Basically I want to reinitialize the grid Options again when click on one particular Event. I came across this functionality in AG Grid [api.redrawRows(redrawRowsParams)](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/view-refresh/) where it Removes the rows from the DOM and draws them again from scratch. The cells are created again from scratch. No change detection is done. No refreshing of cells is done.

But I am using Angular js and grid Options in my project. So I want to know if we have anything similar like this in that.

I tried reinitializing the $onInit function and registerApi by calling it from the refresh method but still the grid Options are not getting reinitialized , So Can someone please let me know if we have anything similar like this.

Thanks in Advance!